# SQL Server 2008 Management Studio - Running Parameterized Query

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2008

I'd like to be able to run an already parameterized query from within the SSMS:

```
select name
from aTable
where id = @id
```

I know that other IDEs (e.g. TOAD) allow for parameter binding - is this available in SSMS 2008?

Thanks!

Comment: SQLCMD lets you use parameters

sqlcmd -E -i restoredb.sql -v root="c:\myroot"

RESTORE DATABASE MyDB
    FROM DISK = '$(root)\mydb.bak'
    WITH REPLACE,
    MOVE 'mydb_data' to '$(root)\mydb.mdf',
GO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible.

What I usually do in this case is just add the following to the top of the window:

```
declare @id int
set @id = 10

-- followed by the parameterized query
```

Actually, I think 2008 supports initialization now:

```
declare @id int = 10
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing, too - I had hoped for something along the lines of the Template Parameter binding feature :)

Answer (score 2):

I would typically use the `CTRL-Shift-M` functionality in SSMS. See following example with instructions. Bit tedious but hey, better than nothing.

```
--===============================================  
-- Purpose: Search all objects for specified Text  
--===============================================  
-- Instructions: CTRL-A + CTRL-Shift-M, enter text   
-- to search, click Ok and press F5.  
-- To repeat search with other text: CTRL-Z (undo)  
-- and then repeat above.  
SELECT o.Name   AS [Object Name]  
    ,o.xType AS [Object Type]  
    ,s.TEXT  AS [Object Text]  
FROM sySobjects o,  
     sysComments s  
WHERE  o.Id = s.Id  
  AND TEXT LIKE '%&lt;Text To Search,,&gt;%'
```